# Not working if-function, maybe wrong variable? (beginner)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a code for a 'calculator' for my first project ever. Yet the script doesn't want to work. I've tried the first three lines of code and they seemed to work fine.

But as soon as I add the if-function the program crashes. I don't know where I've maken a mistake so I hope someone can help me out here. I'm already looking online for an answer but most beginner courses seem to avoid my question.

Here is the script I've written.

PS: I'm a beginner and a big noob so I literaly know about nothing really so I hope it's not a too irrelevant question.

```
    print("Chose which math function")

KB = input("1) Addition  2) Subtraction  3) Multiplication  4) Division: ")

num1 = input("Give number 1: ")
num2 = input("Give number 2: ")


if KB == 1
    
    result1 = float(num1) + float(num2)
    print(result1)

elif KB == 2
    
    result2 = float(num1) - float(num2)
    print(result2)
    
elif KB == 3
    
    result3 = float(num1) * float(num2)
    print(result3)
    
elif KB == 4
    
    result4 = float(num1) / float(num2)
    print(result4)
    
else
    print(Wrong function)
    

input("Exit")
```

Comment: Always include the full error message in the question. It contains all the relevant context of the error. But it's most likely due to you missing a colon at each if-elif-else statement.

Comment: input will result in a string, you need to cast to int in addition to the missing colons.

Comment: @Phix the blocks within the `if` convert the strings to floats

Comment: @DaveCosta Sure, but an int won't ever compare true against a string.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman yup, I wasn't considering that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use a colon after logic expression.

```
if KB == 1:
    result1 = float(num1) + float(num2)
    print(result1)
```

Comment: Many answers get down votes when they're answering questions that should be closed for being off-topic. This question is most likely off-topic as it's a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a colon (:) to the end of the if/elif/else statements. You also need to change `KB` to an int.

```
if int(KB) == 1:
    result = float(x1) + float(x2)
    print(result)
elif int(KB) x == 2:
    do other thing
else:
    do other thing
```

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to explicitly cast the result to a string.  `print()` generally handles any primitive type.

Comment: oops youre right, my bad